# Memory leak pList array with analyzer - how to resolve?

Tags: objective-c, object, memory, copy, retain

I have a project where I am loading an array of dictionary objects from a pList file and then iterating through them to instantiate some "Chapter" for the app. The analyzer tells me I have a memory leak but if I release the dictionary object from the pList the app crashes. I understand the basics of memory management but I am a bit confused about whether to retain or copy the value from the pList. Below is the code:

```
NSArray *chapterDictsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

//Create array to hold all chapeters and levels 

mChapters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//(this value is synthesized as @synthesized chapters = mChapters;
// defined in the header @property (nonatomic, readonly) NSMutableArray *chapters;

NSMutableDictionary *eachChapterDict = nil;
for (eachChapterDict in chapterDictsArray) {
    //Create a chpater from each
    ChapterData *aChapter = [[ChapterData alloc] initWithDictionary:eachChapterDict];
    //[aChapter trace];
    //Only add those that are enabled
    if(aChapter.enabled || [aChapter isComingSoon] == YES)
    {
        [mChapters addObject:aChapter];
    }
    [aChapter release];
}
// [chapterDictsArray release];//<--uncommenting this causes the app to crash

//Set last level of game flag so we know its the last when completed
ChapterData *veryLastChapter = [mChapters objectAtIndex:[mChapters count]-2];
//Analyzer states potential leak here of an object stored in chapterDictsArray (has a retain count of +1) ???
```

I am wondering whether the way I am handling my properties in the Chapter class is the probelm as in the initWithDictionary method I wrote I am assigning and retaining properties like this:

```
self.enabled = [[aChapterDictionary objectForKey:@"enabled"] boolValue]; //header file @property (nonatomic, assign)BOOL enabled;

//and 
 self.instructions = [aChapterDictionary objectForKey:@"instructions"];//@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString* title;
```

Should I be copying these values instead. Just confused how to clean this mess up so the analyzer stops reporting it. BTW the app runs frin and these objects are around for the lifetime of the app so don't cause any issues currently but I am certain I am doing something wrong (or a few things wrong).

Can someone translate the analyzers warnings for me please?

Comment: (1) What is the surrounding scope of the code fragment you have posted?  Is this part of a method?  (2) You note that `[chaptersArray release]` causes the app to crash.  Where is `chaptersArray` defined?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear - there was a typo where I had refactored my code but xCode hadn't renames chaptersArray to chapterDictsArray . I have just updated it. "chapters" is a synthesized NSMutable Array I am populating.

Comment: Hmmm...baffled.  I don't see any reason why the app would crash on `[chapterDictsArray release]` based on what you've shown here, otherwise you do have a leak - as you point out. What is the exception that is being thrown?

Comment: I get what I think is over release error (EXC_BAD_ACCESS code = 1 address 0xe8240489). I can only assume that when I release that chapterDictsArray a variable is being overreleased which should have earlier been copied/retained when I populate the new array with Chapter instances. 

Do I need to do: 

    ChapterData *aChapter = [[ChapterData alloc] initWithDictionary:[eachChapterDict copy]];

Comment: My recommendation is to use Instruments to help verify that the exception refers to `chapterDictsArray` [See this, on Instruments.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html)  This: `ChapterData *aChapter = [[ChapterData alloc] initWithDictionary:[eachChapterDict copy]];` would cause more objects to leak.

Comment: Thanks NSBum for the link - I will check it out with instruments and see if I can see what is happening.

Comment: I fixed this issue - for the record it was because I was accidentally releasing a value of the NSDictionary "eachChapterDict" passed through to the Chapter initWithDictionary method - so an overrelease problem. Hard to track down though but with Instruments it was easier. Thanks again NSBum